# Export/Import Hyper V Virtual Machine from Hyper-V Manager 6.3

Tags: import, export, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I need a help. I have Hyper V Manager 6.3 Version and Windows 2012 Server, and i export my Hyper-V Virtual Machine. Now that export i need to import on other server which is Windows Server 2008 R2, and it has Hyper V Manager 6.1 Version.

When I import there that export, gives me this error:

*"Import failed. Import failed. Unable to find virtual machine import files under location … You can import a virtual machine only if you used Hyper-V to create and export it.”*

Please help me how to solve this error. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hyper-V doesn't support moving a VM from a newer version of Hyper-V to an older version.  With that said, try copying the vhd (keep a backup, I don't know that this will work), make a new VM, and when it asks if you want to make a new VHD, connect it to the one you copied. The new VM will need the same general configuration as the one you're trying to move.

We changed a lot between 2008R2 and 2012.  It may be that some things are broken when you move the VM.